# Remove element from list containing special characteristic except when next to another character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If the list is

```
value=["Jane.Doe@gmail.com", "John.Doe@gmail.com", "JaneDoe@gmail.com"]
```

I would want the desired list to remove every element that contains "." except with ".com"

```
value=["JaneDoe@gmail.com"]
```

I tried using list comprehension but it removes all the elements

```
email[:] = [x for x in email if x != "."]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to split the email by "@", then test the first part.

```py
>>> email = "Jane.Doe@gmail.com"
>>> email.split("@")
['Jane.Doe', 'gmail.com']
>>> email.split("@")[0]
'Jane.Doe'
```

Put it together

```py
>>> email_list = ["Jane.Doe@gmail.com", "John.Doe@gmail.com", "JaneDoe@gmail.com"]
>>> email_list = [email for email in email_list
                  if "." not in email.split("@")[0]]
>>> email_list
['JaneDoe@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
value = ["Jane.Doe@gmail.com", "John.Doe@gmail.com", "JaneDoe@gmail.com"]

value = [v for v in value if "." not in v.replace(".com", "")]
print(value)
```

Prints:

```py
['JaneDoe@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print ".com"

```
value=["Jane.Doe@gmail.com", "John.Doe@gmail.com", "JaneDoe@gmail.com"]
test = [x[-4:] for x in value]
```

Output

```
['.com', '.com', '.com']
```